# Can anyone help me with a recursive function in racket?

Tags: racket

I am writing a recursive function. But the question requires you not to use the exponential function. Can anyone show me how to get larger powers by multiplying smaller powers by a?

Input `a=2` `n=4`. Then get`[2, 4, 8, 16]`
Input `a=3` `n=4`. Then get`[3 9 27 81]`.
I was trying to multiply `a` by `a` each time, so when I input 2 and 4. I get `[2 4 16 256]`. So what should I do?

Here is what I have written:

```
(define (input a n)
    (if (= n 0)
        '()
        (append (cdr (list [* a a] a))
        (let ((a (* a a)))
        (input a (- n 1))))))
```

Comment: If that's what you're getting then you're not multiplying a*a, you're multiplying your accumulator by your accumulator. In any case, without code, not a reasonable question--SO isn't HaaS.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem wrong, you really need two recursive functions (one to build the list and one to build each element). I am assuming you are allowed to use local, but if you aren't you could move that into a helper function.

```
(define (build-sqr-list a n)
    (local [(define (sqr-recurse a n)
          (if (= n 0)
              1
              (* a (sqr-recurse a (sub1 n)))))]
    (if (= n 0)
        '()
        (cons (sqr-recurse a n) (build-sqr-list a (sub1 n))))))
```